# how to print a statement only once when the print statement is inside a class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, printing, object-oriented-analysis

```
codeList = []
code = ''

class codeInitiator():

    def __init__(self):
        self.code = code 
        
    def codeGenerator(self):
        #this function is too long but what is basically does is generate random code using randint etc 
        #and assigns it to the self.code variable.

        codeNoter()

    def codeNoter(self):

        codeList.append(self.code) 
        print(codeList)

    def execProcesses(self):
        
        self.codeGenerator()


a = codeInitiator()
b = codeInitiator()
c = codeInitiator()
a.execProcesses()
b.execProcesses()
c.execProcesses()
```

the problem here is that the list is being printed thrice, first with one code, second time with the first and second code, and the third time with the first, second, and the newer third code. i want it so that the list prints only once such that it includes all the codes at once, not every time. i tried using the "adding +1 to a variable and using conditionals" method but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Move the `.append(...)` and `print` statements to separate methods. That being said, a class should not modify global variables. That defeats the purpose of OOP.

Comment: Add an optional parameter to `codeNoter` to enable/disable printout.

Comment: @Selcuk but if the variables are not global, how else can i access them outside the class?

Comment: There are various patterns, but one way is to pass the variable to the method and get it back. You may also consider making it an instance attribute. It all depends on your use case.

Comment: @Selcuk ok bro thanks!